# Only Render Horizontally

Tags: css

I want to be able to render--let's say `div`s--only horizontally (and display a horizontal scroll bar if the `div`s run off the screen). I am attempting to mimic the ability to add "Lists" in Trello, as the "Lists" only render horizontally. How might I be able to achieve this?

Comment: I've tried setting a width (let's call it "w") on the parent container of the `div`s, but once the width reaches "w", the `div`s start rendering on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the parent to ignore wrapping. The children needs to be set `inline-block`

```css
.render-x-axis {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.block {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/400x400');
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="render-x-axis">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make it display only horizontally (no matter how many `div`s are present). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Edited the answer to your requirement.